# Why this code DOES NOT return a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String []ar)
   {
      A m = new A();
      System.out.println(m.getNull().getValue());
   }
}

class A
{
   A getNull()
   {
      return null;
   }

   static int getValue()
   {
      return 1;
   }
}
```

I came across this question in an SCJP book. The code prints out `1` instead of an NPE as would be expected. Could somebody please explain the reason for the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It behaves as it should according to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#d5e19846):

> a null reference may be used to access a class (static) variable without causing an exception.

Answer (score 22):

Basically you're calling a static method *as if* it were an instance method. That just gets resolved to a static method call, so it's as if you'd written:

```
A m = new A();
m.getNull();
System.out.println(A.getValue());
```

IMO the fact that your code is legal at all is a design flaw in Java. It allows you to write very misleading code, with `Thread.sleep` as an example I always use:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(someRunnable);
thread.start();
thread.sleep(1000);
```

Which thread does that send to sleep? The current one, "of course"...

Answer (score 6):

Static method calls are resolved at compile time. The Compiler sees that `getNull()` has a return value of type `A` which has a static `getValue()` method (and no instance method of the same name), so in the bytecode, the actual return value of `getNull()` is ignored and `A.getValue()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

getNull function returns an A object.
getValue is declared as static, and just needs class_name to function, as in A.getValue(). Because getNull returns (in fact) an A object...you will get 1

Answer (score 1):

**System.out.println(m.getNull().getValue());** 
this line of code is same as
**System.out.println(A.getValue());**

as because **getValue()** method is static and and *all static call initiate at compile time in java*. so it does not produce any error once you make **getValue()** in non static this will produce error as because it will be called at run time

Comment: This is incorrect, `m.getNull()` **does** get called. See Jon's answer.

Comment: m.getNull() will be called only if getNull is not static. which i mentioned earlier.

Comment: What I meant is that `System.out.println(m.getNull().getValue());` is not equivalent to `System.out.println(A.getValue());`. It is equivalent to `m.getNull(); System.out.println(A.getValue());`.